# How to draw a line with changing intensity/grayscale

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, plot

If I have matrix/data with line intensity values:
e.g.

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..... M  (where intensity value is gradually changing)
or
any random order of values

So if I use the first intensity set of data, (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..... M), my line color should be gradually turning black to white. If I remember correctly, 0 is used to represent black and 255 is used to represent white? I would like to use a data of intensity values to draw 3D line with changing color/intensity.

How can I draw a 3D line with changing intensity/grayscale? I would appreciate any advice or recommendation.

Comment: Can you please review the question/title and rephrase/correct the mistakes such that one can understand what is being asked.

Comment: Oops I forgot to finish writing my question title :D Its fixed now

Comment: This question is very poorly explained. Can you give an example of what you mean? What does the matrix with intensity values that are "linearly increasing, but can be of any value" have to do with the question? What does the coordinate system have to do with anything?

Comment: I tried to take out unnecessary phrases I wrote, and gave an example. I hope this clarifies my questions...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [3D colored line plot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23566-3d-colored-line-plot) tool from the file exchange and change the colormap to whatever you need.

[image]